# Qt 5.8 bug on El Capitan

Tags: qt, osx-elcapitan

I recently updated one of my computers to El Capitan, but I noticed some weird behaviours on my project. For example :
I have a QCombobox with images, I set the size policy setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox::AdjustToContents). If I run the project on OS X 10.9.5 I get the desired result: the QCombobox is resized to show the whole image, if I run it on the computer with El Capitan instead, the Combobox stays the "standard" size (one text line).
Similarly I had a few Qlabels in which I set the font to Wingdings using

```
QFont arrowFont("Wingdings");
lblArrow->setFont(arrowFont);
```

on 10.9.5 I get the desired symbols, on El Capitan on the other hand I get a normal font.
Does anyone have any experience with Qt on El Capitan and can give me some insight on why this is?

Comment: File a bug report http://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: I was thinking about it but I first wanted to make sure it really was a bug and not some setting I had to change or something. I also tried adding Wingdings as a resource and loading it from there but it doesn't seem to work either.